# For $P_{i}=X(X-1) \ldots(X-i+1)$, decompose $P_{i}^{*}$ in terms of $f_{i}: P \mapsto P(i)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I know $P_{i}=X(X-1) \ldots(X-i+1)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{K}_{n}[X]$ for i=0 to n and $f_{i}: P \mapsto P(i)$ is a basis of $(\mathbb{K}_{n})^{*}$ but I am having serious difficulty representing the $P_{i}^{*}$ in terms of $f_{i}: P \mapsto P(i)$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $P_i^*$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that $\{P_1^*,\dots,P_n^*\}$ is meant to denote the dual basis of $\{P_1,\dots,P_n\}$.

Note that
$$
f_i(P_j) = \begin{cases}
0 & i < j\\
(i)_j & i \geq j.
\end{cases}
$$
Where $(i)_j = i\cdot (i-1)\cdots \cdot (i - j + 1)$.  Our goal is to find coefficients $a_{ij}$ such that $\sum_{k} a_{ik}f_k(P_j) = \delta_{ij}$, since this would imply that $P_i^* = \sum_k a_{ik}f_k$. In terms of matrix multiplication, we are looking for a matrix $A$ (with entries $a_{ij}$) for which $A B = I$, where $B$ has entries $b_{ij} = f_i(P_j)$.

In other words, once we calculate $A = B^{-1}$, the answer is $P_i^* = \sum_k a_{ik}f_k$.

For $n = 4$, this looks like
$$
B = \pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 6 & 6 & 0\\
4 & 12 & 24 & 24}\implies
A = B^{-1} = 
\frac 1{24}\pmatrix{
24 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-24 & 12 & 0 & 0\\
12 & -12 & 4 & 0\\
-4 & 6 & -4 & 1}
$$